# Turborepo deployment in aws amplify error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, monorepo, turborepo

Iam building a monorepo using turborepo, i have two nextjs project under apps folder, one called chat another one called web, when I try to deploy it on AWS AMPLIFY, I am encountering an error during the build process

```
f2023-07-01T07:37:37.020Z [INFO]: • Packages in scope: web
                                 • Running build in 1 packages
                                 • Remote caching disabled
2023-07-01T07:37:37.020Z [INFO]: web:build: cache miss, executing a42a564a285c792f
2023-07-01T07:37:37.564Z [INFO]: web:build:
                                 web:build: > web@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src1119265180/src/dev-Frontend/apps/web
                                 web:build: > next build
                                 web:build:
2023-07-01T07:37:37.602Z [INFO]: web:build: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
                                 web:build:   throw err;
                                 web:build:   ^
                                 web:build:
                                 web:build: Error: Cannot find module '/codebuild/output/src1119265180/src/dev-Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.7_biqbaboplfbrettd7655fr4n2y/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
                                 web:build:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
                                 web:build:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
                                 web:build:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
                                 web:build:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
                                 web:build:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
                                 web:build:   requireStack: []
                                 web:build: }
```

Here is the relevant portion of my amplify.yml file:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: apps/web
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm install -g pnpm
        build:
          commands:
            - npx turbo run build --filter=web
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: apps/web/.next
        files:
          - "**/*"
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
      buildPath: /

  - appRoot: apps/chat
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm install -g pnpm
        build:
          commands:
            - npx turbo run build --filter=chat
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: apps/chat/.next
        files:
          - "**/*"
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
      buildPath: /
```

My root package.json

```
{
  "name": "dev-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "turbo run dev",
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "lint": "turbo run lint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "pnpm": "6",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
    "turbo": "^1.10.6"
  },
  "packageManager": "pnpm@6.32.3"
}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error, Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have `next.js` on your workspaces?

Comment: @AllanChua Yes, I have next.js on both workspace.

Comment: Then the `node_modules` from those workspaces were not found by the build process.

Comment: @AllanChua, Yes, adding pnpm i on prebuild fixed the issue, thanks you.
 Now the build is successful but the deployed link says the page isn't working